# How do I add a new text value from a WPF textbox to a database using the Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I have a problem with adding text to the database, namely I have three tables:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvpUg.png)

In WPF, the registration looks like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wEDA.png)

In buttonSend I added such a code:

```
private void ButtonRegister_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        model.Imie = Imie.Text.Trim();
        model.Nazwisko = Nazwisko.Text.Trim();
        model.Pesel = PESEL.Text.Trim();
        model.Adres.Ulica = Ulica.Text.Trim();
        model.Adres.Numer_domu = NumerD.Text.Trim();
        model.Adres.Numer_mieszkania = NumerM.Text.Trim();
        model.Kontakt.Telefon = Telefon.Text.Trim();
        model.Kontakt.email = Email.Text.Trim();

        using (eDoctorEntities db = new eDoctorEntities())
        {
            db.Pacjents.Add(model);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        MessageBox.Show("Zarejestrowano !");
}
```

The program throws an error:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'The object reference has not been set to the instance of the object.'

on the line

```
model.Adres.Ulica = Ulica.Text.Trim();
```

How to fix this? Please help me.

Comment: maybe ur passing null or empty to the field so u getting this error.

Comment: Where did you create model? var model = new BlaBlaClass(); add this in method.So please share model class.

Comment: @codelover Pacjent model = new Pacjent(), it exists in the same class as a global object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before setting

```
model.Adres.Ulica = Ulica.Text.Trim();
```

you should initialize Adres

```
model.Adres = new Adres();
```

Comment: Thank you ! This is solution ! +1 like :)

Comment: So you can add "this.Adres = new Adres();" in constructor at Pacjent class.

Answer (score 0):

you must first add adress model then add to model clas like this code :

```
        model.Imie = "your text";
        model.Nazwisko = "your text";
        model.Pesel = "your text";
        Adres adres = new Adres();
        adres.Ulica = "your text";
        adres.Numer_domu = "your text";
        adres.Numer_mieszkania = "your text";
        model.Adress = adres; 
...
```

and your model classes like this classes:

```
 public class Model
{
    public string Imie { get; set; }
    public string Nazwisko { get; set; }
    public string Pesel { get; set; }
    public Adres Adress { get; set; }
}

public class Adres
{
    public string Ulica { get; set; }
    public string Numer_domu { get; set; }
    public string Numer_mieszkania { get; set; }
}
...
```